# Circuit analysis to understand how this circuit works - PNP

Tags: voltage, pnp, step-down, variable

[image: LTspice Schematic]

I am trying to understand how to get values at midpoint_diode and also at OUT.

I understand this circuit is to step-down the voltage from Vin to something that is lower and also it used to have a constant (small variation) on OUT even if Vin fluctuates between a certain range.

I am trying to do a circuit analysis to identify how to get the different voltages at different points and how in general the circuit works.

Comment: Are D1 and D2 supposed to be zeners? I don't see the point of them otherwise.

Comment: Yes they are.  @Hearth

Comment: You've drawn them as Schottkys, complete with the part number of a Schottky diode. They will do nothing significant as drawn.

Comment: Correction - it supposed to be esd diode. just to protect from esd.

Comment: ESD protection diodes in this configuration are always zeners.

Comment: @Hearth Noted will take note of this

Comment: @Hearth First thought was "zener." Then I read the number and said "schottky?" Then I was wondering about why, as the ideality factor of any pair of random schottky's would be different and the leakage would likely be orders of magnitude different depending upon which one was which end up. No two pairs used would ever the same, leakage wise. Couldn't be some unusual "desired leakage" thing. So right back to "zener". Only thing that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here are what you want ... Simulated with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/micro-cap-12-full-cd-version-12.2.0.5).

Vm is very "low" because diode D2 is "direct" polarized.
As Breakdown voltage is 20 V for the diodes, they are not "usable" and do "nothing" (if Vin < 20 V).
Q1 does not conduct if abs(Vbe) < 0.6 V which occurs when 1.5k*Vin/(12k+3.82k+3.9k+1.5k) = ~ 0.6 V -> Vin (Vin = ~ 8.5 V where V(out) begins to "saturate").

[image]

Comment: That formula you mentioned is generated because you're finding the Vmid at OUT correct? Any reason why 1.5K and 3.9K is not being series-ed together to get the Reqv.

Comment: What does "direct polarized" mean? Do you mean forward-biased?